# How to flatten the nested try-catch block in F#?

Tags: f#, entity-framework-core

How to flatten the nested try-catch block in F# for the following code? I am using **EF Core** with F#. **The nested is required because I need to Rollback the transaction if there are errors in saving or committing the transaction!**

```
let createTenant (ctx: AppContext) (tenant: Db.Tenant) (firstUser: Db.User) =
    async {
        try
            let! db = ctx.Aquire()
            
            use! transaction = db.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.Serializable) |> Async.AwaitTask

            db.Tenant.Add tenant |> ignore
            db.User.Add firstUser |> ignore

            let! result =
                async {
                    try
                        let! _ = db.SaveChangesAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                        do! transaction.CommitAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                        
                        return Ok tenant.Id
                    with
                    | _ ->
                        do! transaction.RollbackAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                        return Error "internal error"
                }

            ctx.Release()

            return result

        with
        | _ -> return Error "internal error"
    }
```

On a side note, is this the clean/idiomatic way to handle exceptions in F#? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You don't need the inner `try/catch`. If `SaveChangesAsync()` errors then the transaction will be rolled back anyway and you jump into the outer `try/catch`.

Comment: @GertArnold I am new to EF Core. Does it automatically rollback the transaction if there are errors in `SaveChangesAsync()` or `CommitAsync()` method?

Comment: Yep. It's all or nothing with these methods.

Comment: @GertArnold. Thanks. That explains it very well and makes complete sense.

Comment: Not related to question, but since you're working mostly with TPL and `Task` class, it would be better to use [Ply](https://github.com/crowded/ply) or [TaskBuilder](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs) to avoid usage of `Async.AwaitTask` which might be slow and gives better interop experience when your library is called from other languages